# Processing a maximum number of tasks per consumer in a topic, for a given time window?

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, faust

My producer generates `n` tasks from a single input message and publishes these on `topic`.

The requirement is that out of all the individual consumers in the consumer group of `topic`, no one of them should process more than 3 of any of these `n` tasks within 1 hour.

This means that if I want to process all these messages immediately, I need at least `ceil(n/3)` consumers. If there are fewer than `ceil(n/3)` consumers then I need some way of deferring a message until there have been `num_processed < 3` in the last hour.

In terms of practicalities to implement this solution, I am hoping to use Kafka with Faust [1] but I also have access to Redis if necessary.

My idea so far has been to ensure that there are at least `ceil(n/3)` consumers when producing and then just use round-robin assignment of tasks to `topic` by the producer. This is the optimal solution anyway because it prevents needing to ever wait up to 1 hour to process messages. However this would only work until enough consumers die whereupon more than 3 could be processed by the same consumer most likely within 1 hour. This is unacceptable.

Another idea might be to have the consumers check each time they take a message whether they have executed 3 of the `n` tasks already and if so, somehow request that another consumer works on it - but I could not find any suitable mechanism in Kafka to enable this.

[1] https://faust.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Not sure about faust, but you can set `max.poll.records=3`, then poll indefinitely until you actually get 3 records, then processes them, and commit those offsets and repeat.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure that would prevent the processing of more than 3 of the n related messages by the same consumer?

Comment: If you limit the consumer to only poll three messages, and break the loop if not, there is no way it can accept more than that

Comment: But after processing those 3 messages, that same consumer may fetch another 3 of the same set of n messages, within 1 hour.

Comment: Only if you continue the poll loop

Comment: Can you elaborate in an answer please?

Comment: Again, I don't know faust. In almost all Kafka consumer code, you have `while (true) records = consumer.poll(time)`. Remove/edit the loop condition. Check if the `len(records) >= 3`

Comment: I don't *have* to use Faust. I'm just struggling to understand your suggestion in terms of when not polling the loop, you're not sitting idle.

Comment: You don't have to use a loop, basically. Hourly cron works as well

Comment: Maybe I did not describe the problem well enough. But these n tasks come in regularly. I don't want a consumer to sit idle when it could start working on 3 more of the tasks from the same topic but which are related to a different set of n tasks.

Comment: Alright, then you need some infinite loop  to keep polling. And you can check the amount of records that have been returned since the last time around. If you don't get enough records, then discard that batch and let Kafka internals tell the applicatoin to re-fetch data

Answer (score 0):

Something that would require a bit more effort, but would make the actual processing a lot easier, is to have a pre-consumer that would simply wait until there's 3 messages to consume, package them up in a "meta-message", and send that to a **"ready-for-processing**" topic.  It would have to be like @cricket_007 mentioned, it shouldn't commit until it actually has consumed 3 messages *and* produced them into the outbound topic.

This way, the final consumer is an extremely simple one.  It would simply consume from the "**ready-for-processing**" topic, and anytime it gets a message, you *know* it will have the 3 events you need.  You simply process them, and wait another hour until you can poll again.  There would be no need to coordinate with any other consumers.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the issue is not that one consumer needs to process 3 events together, rather it needs to only process a maximum of 3 events per hour out of a larger set of n events. If there are fewer than 3 events for example, they still need to be (and can be) processed immediately

Comment: @deed02392 Sounds like you first want to window events into hourly segments

Comment: I think that would force a delay of 1 hour though, even if there were actually enough consumers to distribute all the tasks to be processed immediately?